Cannot find entry symbol _start (NASM, ld, ELF64)
I've been following a guide on assembly to learn NASM but I can't get ld to work.
This is main.asm:
section .text
        global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
        mov     rdx, len    ;message length
        mov     rcx, msg    ;message to write
        mov     rbx, 1      ;fd to use is stdout
        mov     rax, 4      ;sys_write
        int     0x80        ;call kernel
        mov     rax, 1      ;sys_exit
        int     0x80        ;call kernel

section .data

msg     db      'Hello world!', 0xa
len     equ     $ - msg                 ;length of the string

And I'm using the following command.
nasm -f elf64 main.asm && ld -o main main.o  && ./main
Which prints out:
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
./run.sh: line 1: ./main: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
I've tried using GCC but I get the same issue, except with main instead of _start.

Works here. Make sure you used the exact code and commands you posted. Note that main should not even exist if the command fails so getting an "exec format error" is already extremely suspicious. Also you are not using an ARM machine by any chance? PS: int 0x80 is the old 32 bit interface, do not use in 64 bit code. See What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?

Wow I'm an idiot. I had 2 folders, one called Assembly, the other called NASM. One terminal window was saving the asm file to one folder while my script was running in a different folder. It works now. Thanks.
